# 'docker cp' command in Jenkins docker container copies a file into a directory

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, docker

I am running a Jenkins server in a docker container.

I started the Jenkins container by the following command:

> sudo docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -d weizhou/jenkins

In a Jenkins job, I want to copy the builded .war to the local machine (i.e. out of the docker container) and to launch another Tomcat docker server. However, the file in the docker file become a **directory** after I use the command `docker cp`, that is, the rpm.war file become a rpm.war directory and nothing in it. How should I solve this problem, thanks very much.

Below are my script post in the `Execute shell` in a jenkins job.

```
sudo docker exec tomcat  /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
sudo docker rm -f tomcat
sudo rm /home/rpm.war
sudo docker cp jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/rpm/target/rpm.war /home/
sudo chmod 777 /home/rpm.war
sudo docker run --name tomcat --link mysql:mysql  -p 80:8080 -v /home/rpm.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rpm.war --rm -d tomcat:7.0.75-jre7
```

Here are the Jenkins console:

```
[rpm] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1380760968175739587.sh
+ sudo docker exec tomcat /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
+ sudo docker rm -f tomcat
tomcat
+ sudo rm /home/rpm.war
+ sudo docker cp jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/rpm/target/rpm.war /home/
+ sudo chmod 777 /home/rpm.war
+ sudo docker run --name tomcat --link mysql:mysql -p 80:8080 -v /home/rpm.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rpm.war --rm -d tomcat:7.0.75-jre7
205b8551375c1e3667965288d8d3d4240f8be765ea124e1ff57956e801509318
Finished: SUCCESS
```

And the rpm.war is a **directory** and nothing in it!

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-66-12:/home$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    368 Feb 24 09:23 rpmBuild.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Feb 24 09:38 rpm.war
drwxr-xr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 24 09:25 ubuntu
```

Besides, the script can run ok in the local machine and command `docker cp' really copy file as file, rather than a directory.

Furthermore, I use the similar script runing in a real Jenkins rather than in a container, it does work and the file is copied as a file. The similar script is

```
sudo docker exec tomcat  /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
sudo docker rm -f tomcat
sudo rm /home/rpm.war
sudo cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rpm/target/rpm.war /home/
sudo chmod 777 /home/rpm.war
sudo docker run --name tomcat --link mysql:mysql  -p 80:8080 -v /home/rpm.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rpm.war --rm -d tomcat:7.0.75-jre7
```

At last, my jenkins Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y sudo maven\
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER jenkins
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh bouncycastle-api:2.16.0 cloudbees-folder:5.17 structs:1.6 junit:1.20 antisamy-markup-formatter:1.5 pam-auth:1.3 windows-slaves:1.2 display-url-api:1.1.1 mailer:1.19 ldap:1.14 icon-shim:2.0.3 matrix-auth:1.4 token-macro:2.0 script-security:1.26 matrix-project:1.8 external-monitor-job:1.7 build-timeout:1.18 credentials:2.1.11 plain-credentials:1.4 workflow-step-api:2.9 credentials-binding:1.10 timestamper:1.8.8 resource-disposer:0.6 scm-api:2.0.7 workflow-api:2.11 workflow-basic-steps:2.4 ws-cleanup:0.32 ant:1.4 gradle:1.26 workflow-scm-step:2.3 ssh-credentials:1.13 git-client:2.2.1 jquery-detached:1.2.1 workflow-support:2.13 ace-editor:1.1 workflow-cps:2.27 git-server:1.7 workflow-cps-global-lib:2.6 pipeline-milestone-step:1.3 pipeline-build-step:2.4 pipeline-stage-step:2.2 pipeline-input-step:2.5 workflow-job:2.10 pipeline-graph-analysis:1.3 pipeline-rest-api:2.5 handlebars:1.1.1 momentjs:1.1.1 pipeline-stage-view:2.5 durable-task:1.13 workflow-durable-task-step:2.9 pipeline-model-api:1.0.2 pipeline-stage-tags-metadata:1.0.2 authentication-tokens:1.3 docker-commons:1.6 docker-workflow:1.10 pipeline-model-declarative-agent:1.0.2 branch-api:2.0.6 workflow-multibranch:2.12 pipeline-model-definition:1.0.2 workflow-aggregator:2.5 github-api:1.84 git:3.0.5 github:1.26.0 github-branch-source:2.0.3 pipeline-github-lib:1.0 github-organization-folder:1.6 mapdb-api:1.0.9.0 subversion:2.7.1 ssh-slaves:1.13 email-ext:2.57 build-token-root:1.4
```

Comment: What does `sudo docker exec jenkins ls -l /var/jenkins_home/workspace/rpm/target/rpm.war` output. An empty folder is seen often when the source doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem is solved here.    https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/441